# Why doesn't it show the 'greetings' template?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm starting to develop in 'Spring-boot' and I did the 'getting started' as it is and it doesn't show me what it should

[so are the routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atJDi.png)

[this is the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgx6j.png)

here is the code of application.properties

```java
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html # ;charset=<encoding> is added
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

template 'greeting'

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head> 
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'" />
</body>
</html>
```

This is the controller code.

```java
package com.arbaAppWebC.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "greeting";
    }

}
```

```java
package com.ArbaAppWeb.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And this is the dependencies

```java
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

[this appears on the web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4nL7.png)

I am using java 17 as a compiler although I have java 19 installed even so I do not understand what is wrong because I followed the same steps indicated in the spring-boot doc.

I have the same problem since yesterday.

If you need any other information I am at your disposal to give it and be able to obtain the desired solution.

Comment: Your console shows a warning message: `Cannot find template location...`, even though it does appear to exist and does appear to be on the runtime classpath. There may be various reasons why this is happening. You can [research](https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+boot+cannot+find+template+location+site:stackoverflow.com) different suggestions and solutions. You can update your question with the results of your research. (I don't know if this is related to your `404 not found` problem - but it's a good place to start.)

Comment: Note: Please always show text as formatted text (not as screenshots). See a list of reasons why [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12567365).

Comment: what is the real path of the 'templates' folder?

Comment: @JohnWilliams src/main/resources/templates/home.html

Comment: @imnach2 , your GreetingController.java return "greeting";  But your templates use **home.html** ?

Comment: @imnach2 If your template file is named home.html, then you need to return "home", not "greeting"